# Blender 2.8 Cycles Importing Image as Plane isn't transparent

Tags: image, transparency

I'm importing a logo image as a Plane and putting it on top of an object:

[image: My Blender Design]

However, the image appears with the checkered pattern behind the image - not the actual Blender object ... which defeats the purpose of the transparency.

At the same time, even when I render the image completely in cycles, it still shows the checkered pattern!

My material settings for the logo image:

[image: Materials settings 1/2]

[image: Materials settings 2/2]

How can I get rid of the checkered pattern and make the image truly transparent and blended in with the objects in my scene?

Comment: Are you sure that the image has an alpha channel and the pattern isn't in the image?

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That got it.  I was scratching my head trying to figure out where I went wrong.  Couldn't believe the pattern is in the image itself, might because I got the image from google images.

Answer (score 1):

@rjg got it right.  Turns out the transparency pattern in the back was inside the image itself - might be because of Google Images.

Everything is working smoothly now!

[image: Working transparent image render]